# Xamarin forms app crashes for unknown reason

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have built a Xamarin forms app with PCL.

The application crashes sometimes for unknown reason : either while scrolling though any of the picker on some pages of the application or while resuming the app after some period of inactivity (may be after 10-15 mins).

I am using Crittercism to report crash logs. I am not getting any stack trace or crash log for this crashes.

Details
Xamarin Studio : 5.9.5(biuld 9)
Xamarin.iOS : Version: 8.10.4.46 (Enterprise Edition)
Xamarin.Android : Version: 5.1.5.3 (Enterprise Edition).

Note : When I was checking in debug mode with device connected : I got 2 kinds of crashes which says : 
1.

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/throwhelper.cs:70 
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Xamarin.Forms.AnimationExtensions+Info].get_Item (System.String key) [0x00000] in :0 
at Xamarin.Forms.AnimationExtensions.HandleTweenerUpdated (System.Object o, System.EventArgs args) [0x00012] in :0 
at Xamarin.Forms.Tweener.b__0 (Int64 step) [0x00037] in :0 
at Xamarin.Forms.Ticker.SendSignals (Int32 timestep) [0x00063] in :0 
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CADisplayLinkTicker.b__0 () [0x00000] in :0 
at Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/maccore/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:56 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46 
at eRedbook.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/s.chandraganesh/Documents/TFS_New/eRedbook/Development/Source/Mobile/iOS/Main.cs:39
```

2. Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
   a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
   used by your application.
   Please help me to narrow down this issue.

Comment: try setting a breakpoint on System.Exception and see where it breaks. This often works a lot better than crash logs for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in [Xamarin.Forms 1.5.1.6471](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28352). Which version are you running on? Upgrading may fix the issue.